# Can I create a CRUD blazor webassembly app that reads from a local SQL DB but doesn't need to be hosted online?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

My only .NET knowledge is from making a couple locally hosted CRUD apps in MVC. Whenever I watch tutorials for Blazor, they talk about a server and APIs. Can I create a CRUD app in Blazor that reads from a local SQL DB but doesn't need to be hosted online but instead makes API calls that are local?

Comment: You can use the local storage from the browser, but the data will be only available in your browser of course. If you need to share the data, you need a server database and a API backend to do your CRUD operations.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Here is a tool that will help you get Blazor application in short time. For either Angular or Blazor frameworks. https://www.radzen.com/features/